# Jackson XML Bind Element based on value of attributes

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb, xml-deserialization

I have the following `XML` structure:

```
<participants>
    <participant side="AWAY">
        <team id="18591" name="Orlando Apollos" />
    </participant>
    <participant side="HOME">
        <team id="18594" name="Memphis Express" />
    </participant>
</participants>
```

If I am using the `FasterXML Jackson` library with `JAXB` annotations how can I bind the participants fields to two different `Participant` objects `participantHome` and `participantAway` using the `side` property of `AWAY` and `HOME` to bind the fields.

Using the following object won't work obviously because there are duplicate fields:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "participants")
public class Participants {

    @XmlElement(name = "participant")
    Participant participantHome;

    @XmlElement(name = "participant")
    Participant participantAway;
}
```

How can I dynamically bind those elements using `JAXB` annotations or a custom `JAXB` implementation?

Comment: What is inside Participant class?

Comment: Participant class just contains the `side` attribute - with a `Team` property object inside. The mappings are as expected. The question I mostly have is around mapping the identical participant element by using the `side`=`AWAY` or `side`=`HOME` attribute value

Comment: In my actual real code I get the following error:


    `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple fields representing property "participant":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write custom deserialiser because there is no annotation which allow to bind list item to given property in object. If you already use `Jackson` try to implement custom [`JsonDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html) instead of custom [`XmlAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html). We can simplify our custom deserialiser by deserialising internal `Participant` objects to `Map`. Simple example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.MapType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File xmlFile = new File("./resource/test.xml").getAbsoluteFile();

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

        Participants result = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlFile, Participants.class);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

class ParticipantsXmlAdapter extends JsonDeserializer<Participants> {

    @Override
    public Participants deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> participants = readParticipantsMap(p, ctxt);

        Participants result = new Participants();
        for (Map<String, Object> participantMap : participants) {
            Object side = participantMap.get("side").toString();
            if ("AWAY".equals(side)) {
                result.setParticipantAway(convert((Map<String, Object>) participantMap.get("team")));
            } else if ("HOME".equals(side)) {
                result.setParticipantHome(convert((Map<String, Object>) participantMap.get("team")));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private List<Map<String, Object>> readParticipantsMap(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        MapType mapType = ctxt.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
        JsonDeserializer<Object> mapDeserializer = ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(mapType);
        List<Map<String, Object>> participants = new ArrayList<>();
        p.nextToken(); // skip Start of Participants object
        while (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            p.nextToken(); // skip start of Participant
            Object participant = mapDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);
            participants.add((Map<String, Object>) participant);
            p.nextToken(); // skip end of Participant
        }

        return participants;
    }

    private Participant convert(Map<String, Object> map) {
        Participant participant = new Participant();
        participant.setId(Integer.parseInt(map.get("id").toString()));
        participant.setName(map.get("name").toString());

        return participant;
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = ParticipantsXmlAdapter.class)
class Participants {

    private Participant participantHome;
    private Participant participantAway;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Participant {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

prints:

```
Participants{participantHome=Participant{id=18594, name='Memphis Express'}, participantAway=Participant{id=18591, name='Orlando Apollos'}}
```

Comment: Great answer thanks. Very helpful. I opted for binding to a list and adding a getter method to filter for home / away team. The primary reason for that was because my actual example was more complex on the parent and I didn't want to add too much custom complexity.

However, your answer closest matches the case that I showed and the answer I wanted in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use List of Participant in place of two different participant.
Annotate **side** with **@XmlAttribute(name = "side", required = true)**.
Then create two different Participant objects and add them to list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I opted for your answer because my parent xml element was more complex than the simplified example above and I felt the other answer (that was perfect for this simple example) was too much for my real world example.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of great answers and alternatives here but I've decided to go with a hybrid of binding with a list and returning the correct `home` or `away` team by implementing getter methods that return the correct home or away team to essentially flatten the `List`. This will reduce the amount of computation when processing the lists throughout the application.

I added the following code to my parent class (to each `home`/`away` participant):

```
Participant getHome() {
    return (Participant) participants.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getSide().equalsIgnoreCase("home"));
}

Participant getAway() {
    return (Participant) participants.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getSide().equalsIgnoreCase("away"));
}
```

Thanks for the help!